# Yii reload page after CGridview Delete

Tags: php, ajax, yii

OK, this is frustrating.

All I simply want to do is reload the page after a CGridView Delete action.
As the Delete is performed VIA Ajax, I cannot seem to reload the page.

I need to do this as I have other data on the page that is dependant on the data that I am deleting.

I have tried in the view

```
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'header'=>'Delete',
'template'=>'{delete}',
'buttons'=>array(
    'delete'=>array(
        'success'=>'function(){
            window.location = location.href;
        }',
    ),
),
```

Also in the delete controller as well

```
echo CHtml::script("
    window.location.reload();
");
Yii::app()->end();
```

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [afterDelete](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#afterDelete-detail) parameter (attribute) which exists in `CButtonColumn` class:

```
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'header'=>'Delete',
'template'=>'{delete}',
'afterDelete'=>'function(link,success,data){
    if(success) { // if ajax call was successful !!!
        if(data == SUCCESS_TEXT) {  // SUCCESS_TEXT the text which you output in your delete action on success
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            alert("Error! not deleted.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Error! delete request failed, see console for mor info");
        console.log(data);
    }
}',
```

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't realise this existed. It worked straight away. BIG THUMBS UP